# unit testing in Typo3. What is the procedure to do it?

Tags: typo3-8.x

I have one question. In any custom extension folder, there is another folder called Tests.
My question is, how can I utilise it inorder to do unit test of each public function of controller and Repository?

What is the procedure to do it?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start writing Unit Test for TYPO3 you should take a look at the official site from TYPO3 (https://wiki.typo3.org/Unit_Testing_TYPO3).
Or read the handout from Oliver Klee (https://github.com/oliverklee/tdd-reader) for an easy entry with his tea example (https://github.com/oliverklee/tea).